# Find the matrix which represents the reflection that maps triangle T2 onto triangle T3

Tags: matrices

http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-QP-JUN13.PDF
Question 8(b)(i)

T2 Vertices $(1, 3)$, $(1, 6)$ and $(3, 3)$

Line: $\,\, y=\sqrt 3\, x$

How do you work this out? I am confused as to why this question only gives 2 marks? I have absolutely no idea how you would work this out?

In fact if anyone could go over the entire Question and how you work out each part I would really appreciate it, or at least guide me to a place I can learn how I've looked everywhere and cannot find anything. Regards Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  an instance of the general problem: find the matrix of a reflection with respect to a line through the origin, that has a polar angle $\theta$. In this problem, $\theta=\frac\pi3$.

Change orthonormal basis: take as unit vectors the unit vector on the line, and the unit vector that makes an angle of $\frac\pi2$ with the first one. The change of basis matrix is then $$P=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
(its column vectors are the coordinates of the new unit vectors). It is the matrix for the rotation of angle $\theta$ around the origin.

Now let $X$ be the column vector of coordinates of a point in the canonical basis, $X'$ its vector of coordinates in the new basis. they're linked through the relation $X=PX'$ The matrices $A$ and $A'$ of any linear transformation in the old and new bases respectively are linked through:
$$A'=P^{-1}AP\iff A=PA'P^{-1}.$$
The reason for this formula is that, if a point $X$ has reflection $Y$ as  (in the canonical base), then  $Y=AX$. Now, this can be rewritten in function of the coordinates $X'$ and $Y'$ in the new basis: $PY'=APX'$, hence $Y'=P^{-1}APX'=(P^{-1}AP)X'$, which proves the formula.

Now in the new basis the reflection is but the reflection with respect to the first axis, so that 
$$A'=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
Also, $P^{-1}$ is the matrix of the rotation of angle $-\theta$ around the origin:
$$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
Using  the duplication formulae in trigonometry, we get after some computations:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\theta&\sin2\theta\\\sin2\theta&-\cos2\theta\end{bmatrix}.\qquad \mathrm{Here:} \quad A=\begin{bmatrix}-\dfrac12&\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\\\dfrac{\sqrt3}2&\dfrac12\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Some computation details using the slope $\boldsymbol{m=\sqrt 3}$**:

Since $m=\tan\theta\,$ and $-\frac\pi2<\theta <\frac\pi2$, we have:
$\begin{cases}\cos\theta =\frac1{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\\[0.5ex]\sin\theta =\frac m{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\end{cases}$, so that: 
\begin{gather*} 
P=\frac1{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&-m\\m&1\end{bmatrix},\quad P^{-1}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&m\\-m&1\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
A=\dfrac{1}{1+m^2}\begin{bmatrix}1-m^2&2m\\
2m&m^2-1\end{bmatrix}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: It's a good explanation for sure, I just wish it was in laymens terms :P

Comment: @Thomas Winkworth: It's inten,ded as a rough sketch, so as you see the structure of the solution; you're supposed to read it with paper and pencil to check the details. But if you need more explanations on some points, feel free to ask.

Comment: Well literally I need an explanation in laymen terms, just the method to find the matrix. There must be some formulae table/booklet with with a method to solve this equation but have found no-one that can explain in laymen terms. I don't need a proof or how it's derived just the method to find the matrix

Comment: @Thomas Winkworth: I added some details (but you'll still have to compute $PA'P^{-1}$ and simplify the result with trig). Hope it is easier to understand now.

Comment: I have no idea what PA'P^-1 is, I was thinking more along the lines of y=mx and a matrix that used m within it and you would literally plug in sqrt(3) and get your answer

Comment: @Thomas Winkworth: $PAP^{-1}$ is the product of the $3$ matrix $P,A,P^{-1}$. It's only the application of change of basis formula for linear maps. Also I added some computation details that use the slope $m$ (resulting that one can express $\cos\theta $  and $\sin\theta $ with $m=\tan\theta $. My strategy was to avoid elementary, but long and error-prone computations, to use what is known about rotation matrices and linear algebra.